# White page why clicking on a new created button

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I've created a button which is supposed to make a redirection on a new page.
But when I click on it, I got a white page without any information on it.

Here is the `urls.py` for the file.

```
url(r'^layer_quarantine/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='layer_quarantine.html'), name='layer_quarantine'),
```

Here's the file named `_layer_quarantine.html`

```
{% extends "layers/layer_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load url from future %}
{% load base_tags %}

{% block title %} {% trans "Explore Layers" %} - {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}

{% block body_class %}layers explore{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="page-header">
    {% user_can_add_resource_base as add_tag %}
    {% if add_tag %}
  <a href="{% url "layer_upload" %}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">{% trans "Upload Layers" %}</a>
  <a style="margin-right:30px" href="{% url "layer_browse" %}" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
  {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == "fr" %} Toutes les couches {% else %} All layers {% endif %}</a>
    {% endif %} 
  <h2 class="page-title">
  {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == "fr" %} Couches en attente de validation
  {% else %} Layers awaiting validation {% endif %}
  </h2>
</div>


  {% with include_type_filter='true' %}
  {% with facet_type='layers' %}
  {% with header='Type' %}
  {% with filter='type__in' %}
  {% include "search/_search_content.html" %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% with is_layer='true' %}
  {% include "_bulk_permissions_form.html" %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_script %}
  {% if GEONODE_SECURITY_ENABLED %}
    {% include "_permissions_form_js.html" %}
  {% endif %}

  <script type="text/javascript">
      {% if HAYSTACK_SEARCH %}
          SEARCH_URL = '{% url 'api_get_search' api_name='api' resource_name='base' %}?type__in=layer'
      {% else %}
          SEARCH_URL = '{% url 'api_dispatch_list' api_name='api' resource_name='layer_quarantine' %}';
      {% endif %}
    FILTER_TYPE = 'layer';
  </script>
  {% with include_spatial='true' %}
  {% include 'search/search_scripts.html' %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock extra_script %}
```

I have also a `layer_quarantine.html` file

```
{% extends "geonode_base.html" %}

{% load il8n %}

{% %block title %} {% trans "Documents in standby" %} {% endblock %}

{% block body_outer %}
    {% include 'documents/_document_quarantine.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is how I made the button

```
<a style="margin-right:30px" href="{% url "layer_quarantine" %}" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">
```

It would be lovely if someone could help me on this one because I'm on it since a while and I have no idea on how to solve that. I'm not used to do web dev so be kind please.

Comment: template name is different. `_layer_quarantine.html` is not same as `layer_quarantine.html`. if that doesn't work then whats the response status code? can you check your page source and see if there are any html tags present?

Comment: First I thought it was the problem knowing that the templates name wasn't  the same as the one of the file, but when I tried to make `template_name = _layer_quarantine.html` the site crash when I click on the button. 

It's just a white page so I don't have a status code I guess, where can I found this pls ?

Comment: just want to confirm do you have quotes around your template_name value like `template_name = '_layer_quarantine.html'`? and for response code, open your browser inspector and go to network section, then refresh the page. You will see the response code.

Comment: Yes in my `resourcebase_api.py` I have a `resource_name = layer_quarantine`.
The response code is 200.

Comment: can you check if there are any html tags in that blank page?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @Reez0 I'm using django 1.8.19